# Is there a difference in checking a bool first and then assigning it to a variable, versus assigning it and then checking the variable?

Tags: c#

This is more just for the sake of curiosity/learning than a problem.

I'm wondering there's a difference in performance or the intermediate language code in C# if I check if bool is true before assigning it to a variable than the other way around.

```
if (first_bool)
{
  second_bool = first_bool;
  // MORE CODE - needs to be run if the bool is true.
}
```

vs.

```
second_bool = first_bool;
if (second_bool)
{
  // MORE CODE - needs to be run if the bool is true.
}
```

Just to add, I *need* to assign the `second_bool` to the `first_bool` at this point for other uses so I can't just use the `first_bool` all the time. So my question is, is either of the above snippets faster than the other, or do they basically end up the same in terms of IL/performance (besides the ordering of the instructions)?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Check it out yourself: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUARgPYcQEDOApgGMOAOxgB9TtygEpPAGZgATr2CSuEAJRUalbDQMEdhgmHkEWilWrnb9JisYcDhY9dwIBeAldXuIANxOJsjoAJwsAEQAthxK/ATCMPyRmkH2JgC+TtkZRnn4RIxMqOwafEKiEnIycj7KfrZOeg4VrtXl3r42GumtZhbd/natLa3540ThUbHxiRzJqX0OuQa5mUA

Comment: Code it the way its more fitting for the problem to solve. Think about the scope needed for the variables before thinking about performance implications. In the end use the one that makes its more readable. Maybe but just maybe when there are performance consideration after you have it working think about thinks like this. And i'm pretty sure anything else in your code will be more relevant then this.

Comment: @SomeBody. Release code would be more relevant to this. I would assume that its pretty likely that in the executed code one of the bools has been optimized away.

Comment: @Heinzi why? They are the same ... I wouldn't jump to any conclsions without *knowing* what the code actually does ... And if `second_bool` is relevant only within the condition's body, it would be better to define it only in that scope ...

Comment: @derpirscher: There could be further modifications to one of the variables in `// MORE CODE`. But, yes, it's hard to come up with a realistic example.

Comment: I think the first one is potentially faster in the case that the second one will need to insert NOP's to wait for the second_bool to be readable.

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, and therefore we should give our answers/comments based on what we *see*  and not what we *assume*. And if something is unclear, ask for clarification first

Comment: There's a point almost every developer goes through where they decide they're going to learn *all* of the patterns to code for best performance in every circumstance and then just use those rules going forward. The problem is that there are literally billions of rules, with many caveats or disqualifications and *in the vast majority of cases* the performance of the code in question is inconsequential for the users. Don't fall into this trap. If performance is important *here*, measure both alternatives and pick the one that fits your goals.

Comment: Or as Don Knuth put it "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: There is a difference, beyond the logical distinction.  Not at the IL level (just two statements swapped) but at the processor level.  All modern ones are super-scalar, executing multiple instructions at the same time.  When they can, the 2nd snippet however has a data-dependency between the statements that prevents concurrent execution.  Very hard to notice, having 0.3 nanosecond have an impact requires a lot of looping and plenty of bad luck.  Always code for readability first, don't optimize until you really have to.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments - they've all been really helpful in understanding how IL works more. Of course, I prioritize readability when I write code normally. I was just writing something and I was just curious as to whether there's a difference in performance. @derpirscher pointed out in his answer that the second is potentially worse just because it'll do the assignment even if the first_bool is false and the first wouldn't (which is enough in terms of what I want to do)!

Comment: Also @SomeBody thank you for the IL tool, that's really cool! If I'm reading it right, there's no real difference in IL besides the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say, whether these two snippets end up in the same code without seeing the rest of the code, because as they present now, they are semantically different. See the following two snippets. They produce different outputs...

```js
let b1 = false, b2 = true;

if (b1) {
  b2 = b1;
  console.log("do something else")
}
console.log(b1, b2);
```

```js
let b1 = false, b2 = true;
b2 = b1;
if (b2) {
  
  console.log("do something else")
}
console.log(b1, b2);
```

So, whether the two snippets of yours end up in the same IL-code, depends on how for instance `second_bool` is used after the condition's body, on or how it is used in your `//MORE CODE ...` part.

If you really *need* to set the value of `second_bool` for other uses, again it depends whether these "other uses" are inside or outside of your condition's body. If they are, the only way to go is with snippet 2, because with snippet 1 your value may not be set correctly. If they are only within the condition's body, it may be better, to define `second_bool` only within the condition's scope ...

But if that is really a *performance* question, the only valid way is to do a benchmark.

Comment: This is a really interesting point I didn't notice - thank you! Indeed, the second snippet does the assignment regardless of whether the first_bool is true, while the first only does it when it is so.